# Webmatrix 2, missing node.js templates

Tags: node.js, installation, webmatrix

I've installed Webmatrix 2, but only two templates(Asp.net) is installed. How do I install the node.js templates?

Answer (score 1):

You should have three NodeJS templates with the WebMatrix 2 installation.  If not open the Web Platform Installer, and make sure you have WebMatrix 2 Refresh 2 installed.

NOTE: WebMatrix 3 is in Beta, may want to try that.  [WebMatrix 3 Preview Release](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/webmatrix-3-preview-release-notes)

Comment: I've updated to Webmatrix 3 now, but I still have the same problem, no node.js templates. :(